# php mysql insert into syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I am stumped with this syntax error (below):

```
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
    check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
    for the right syntax to use near 
    'desc, barkDesc, flowerDesc, foliageDesc, fruitDesc, type, cat, height, spread, l' 
    at line 1
```

What throws me off is the number 1 after spread like so (height, spread, *1*).

Below is a php print of the INSERT INTO statement which looks great to me.

```
    INSERT INTO plants 
    (botanicalName, commonName, landscapeUses, desc, barkDesc, flowerDesc, foliageDesc, fruitDesc, type, cat, height, spread, lightReq, soil, growth, trimming, fert, otherMaint) 
    VALUES 
    ('Botanical name', 'Common Name', 'Accent, Edge, Groundcover', 'This is some text description text.', 'bark', 'flower', 'foliage', 'fruit', 'Perennial', '', '18 inches', '18 inches', 'full sun', 'well drained', 'medium', 'trimming', 'fertilization', 'other maintenance')
```

And without further ado, MY PHP code

```
       $sql2 = "INSERT INTO plants 
       (botanicalName, commonName, landscapeUses, desc, barkDesc, flowerDesc,  
       foliageDesc, fruitDesc, type, cat, height, spread, lightReq, soil, growth, 
       trimming, fert, otherMaint) 
       VALUES ('$botanicalName', '$commonName', '$usesString', '$desc', '$barkDesc',
       '$flowerDesc', '$foliageDesc', '$fruitDesc', '$type', '$cat', '$height', '$spread', '$lightReq', '$soil', '$growth', '$trimming', '$fert', '$otherMaint')";

       $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
       $plantID = mysql_insert_id();
       header("location: plantdetail.php?plantID=$plantID");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**desc** is a reserved keyword in mysql.

(use backticks to enclose desc)

```
 $sql2 = "INSERT INTO plants (botanicalName, commonName, landscapeUses,
 `desc`, barkDesc, flowerDesc, foliageDesc, fruitDesc, type, cat,
```

--------^

```
  height, spread, lightReq, soil, growth, trimming, fert, otherMaint) 
             VALUES ()";
```

Comment: And? Complete your answer.

Comment: @sectus ya completed it,we need to enclose it within backticks

Comment: @Mr coder, you the man, that worked! I spent probably three hours on this analyzing the insert statement, checking for spellings, etc. I feel so dumb right now, haha. Will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: @BillChambers it happens with everybody :) enjoy coding :)

Comment: @sectus: Many times I feel that there should be a way to restrict commenting until someone completes minimum edit time required on a post, no matter whether it is a question or answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since `desc` is a reserved keyword in MySQL, you need to quote it with backticks:

```
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO plants (botanicalName, commonName, landscapeUses, `desc`, barkDesc, flowerDesc, foliageDesc, fruitDesc, type, cat, height, spread, lightReq, soil, growth, trimming, fert, otherMaint) 
         VALUES ('$botanicalName', '$commonName', '$usesString', '$desc', '$barkDesc', '$flowerDesc', '$foliageDesc', '$fruitDesc', '$type', '$cat', '$height', '$spread', '$lightReq', '$soil', '$growth', '$trimming', '$fert', '$otherMaint')";
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 $sql =   "INSERT INTO plants 
(`botanicalName`, `commonName`, `landscapeUses`, `desc`, `barkDesc`, `flowerDesc`, `foliageDesc`, `fruitDesc`, `type`, `cat`, `height`, `spread`, `lightReq`, `soil`, `growth`, `trimming`, `fert`, `otherMaint`) 
VALUES 
('Botanical name', 'Common Name', 'Accent, Edge, Groundcover', 'This is some text description text.', 'bark', 'flower', 'foliage', 'fruit', 'Perennial', '', '18 inches', '18 inches', 'full sun', 'well drained', 'medium', 'trimming', 'fertilization', 'other maintenance')";
```

Comment: first of all you need to explain about the changes in your code,dont simply write code,include reasons also. :)

Answer (score 0):

As we know that `desc` is a keyword in **mysql**.

so when ever you are using keywords in table column then while using this keywords in query use of `backticks` to prevent error.

**Try it in your case :**

```
    $sql =   "INSERT INTO plants 
             (`botanicalName`, `commonName`, `landscapeUses`, `desc`, `barkDesc`, `flowerDesc`, `foliageDesc`, `fruitDesc`, `type`, `cat`, `height`, `spread`, `lightReq`, `soil`, `growth`, `trimming`, `fert`, `otherMaint`) 
             VALUES 
             ('Botanical name', 'Common Name', 'Accent, Edge, Groundcover', 'This is some text description text.', 'bark', 'flower', 'foliage', 'fruit', 'Perennial', '', '18 inches', '18 inches', 'full sun', 'well drained', 'medium', 'trimming', 'fertilization', 'other maintenance')";
```

for more information about the mysql [KeyWords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

I hope it will help full to you.